# Using external script inside load callback with dialog?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-dialog, anonymous-function

I hope I can explain this properly. I am creating a JQuery dialogue box where the content is loaded from an HTML file. This dialogue box contains a form with which I need to perform additional JS functions. The problem I am running into, is that none of the HTML/selectors exist in the DOM until I click `#image_edit` so my JQuery upload script is not working.
As you can see, I am invoking the upload function on the `.load` callback, but it doesn't work. Is there a better/proper way to do this?

**EDIT :**
After moving the `.dialog` and remote functions inside the `load()` callback, everything is working as expected.

**uploadInterface.js**

```
(function($) {
    $(function(//removed, was not needed//) {
    //upload functions//
    });
})(window.jQuery);
```

**uploadSetup.js**

```
(function($) {
    $(function(//removed, was not needed//) {
    //upload functions//
    });
})(window.jQuery);
```

**dialogue.js**

```
$(function(){
    $('#image_edit').click(function() {
        $(".upload_div").load('../dialogues/content.html #upload_window', function() {

            $.getScript("js/uploadInterface.js"); //added remote script here//
            $.getScript("js/uploadSetup.js"); //added remote script here//

        }).fadeTo("slow", 1).dialog({
            title: "Upload an image",
            width: "320px",
            position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+150' },
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            modal: true,
            show: "fadeIn",
            hide: "fadeOut",
            create: function(event, ui) {
                var widget = $(this).dialog("widget");
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close span", widget)
                .removeClass("ui-icon-closethick")
                .addClass("ui-icon-close-custom");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What would go inside the uploadSetup function? Why can't you have regular functions with selectors and events. Even if the elements do not exist, the functions will work once they are in the DOM later after the load

Comment: I want to keep them separate for manageability, and so I can use them separately throughout the site.

Comment: so are these scripts being loaded in separate js files?

Comment: That is correct, I will edit the question

Comment: and those scripts are being included in the html file that you load? with script tag, right?

Comment: They are not in the loaded HTML file, that is only a series of `<div>` tags with content, but they are included in script tags on the main document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load scripts in jQuery you should use `$.getScript()`
So in your `load` callback function you would have a `$.getScript()` to get the script then execute whatever functions you want.

```
$(".upload_div").load('../dialogues/content.html #upload_window', function() {
    $.getScript( "uploadInterface.js" )
})...
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided a `load()` callback.

Walk through the closing braces in your code and you will see that there is only one argument passed to `load()` and that you are passing a second argument to `dialog()`.

The `load()` method ends as soon as your chain starts `.fadeTo()`

This second argument of dialog is what you have misinterpreted as the callback for `load()`

Comment: I see what you're saying.

Comment: I fixed that part, but the dialogue script still doesn't recognize the upload functions.

Comment: Seems to be a scope issue?

Comment: if `upload script #1` is your function declaration it's all wrong. Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: I clarified the question.

Comment: +1 for pointing out a major issue with the way I was doing it, couldn't have fixed it without your advice.